# Boolean logic question

Tags: ruby, boolean-expression

"true"? "Yes" : "No" , I am using ruby language

This is taking by deafult "yes" even I select "no"

Comment: Please provide _enormous_ amounts of detail.

Comment: Edit your question to post the actual code, copy-pasted from your program.  Also tell us what you are doing specifically, and what the exact results are.  I'm editing tags to include "Ruby"; please use a language tag for future language-dependent questions.

Comment: I am using check box speak_english? == "true"? "Yes" : "No" but it always take no, is there something missing??

Comment: what check box?? check box to store a value (yes/no)...

Comment: There are no check boxes in the ruby language. What you want is `rdf.speak_english?  "Yes" : "No"`

Comment: Are you by chance using Rails and trying to get the value of a checkbox posted in a form?

Answer (score 2):

```
value = condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false
```

is a shortcut for this

```
if condition == true
    value = value-if-true
else
    value = value-if-false
```

If you have a condition that is always evaluated as true, you will always have `value-if-true`. In the example code `"true"` is always a true expression. The only values which are treated as false in an expression are [`false` and `nil`](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/true-false-and-nil-objects-in-ruby/).

Comment: Eh, it would be more accurate to say it's a shortcut for `value = if condition then value_if_true else value_if_false; end` — normal ifs are expressions too in Ruby, and there are a lot of truthy values that aren't equal to true. For example: `1 ? "1 is truthy " + (1 == true ? "and equal to true" : "but not equal to true") : "One is not truthy"`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you're taking, but the value `"true"` is a string. For the boolean value, you want just `true`, with no quotation marks.

Comment: yup you are right, it should be without quotation. thanks.

Comment: xyz.speak_english? == true? "Yes" : "No"

Comment: rdf.speak_english? == true? "Yes" : "No" so that was the code? now